# Angular ngClass/ngIf not rerendering on changes

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an Angular project where I need to have one class or another depending on a variable (and they have to change live, without refreshing).

I tried using *ngIf/else and [ngClass]and they do work but they do not re-render.
They only work when I refresh the website

Using *ngIf/else:

```
<i
 *ngIf="favSongs.includes(track.id); else plus"
 (click)="setToFav(track.id)"
 class="fa fa-check"
></i>
<ng-template #plus>
  <i (click)="setToFav(track.id)" class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</ng-template>
```

Using [ngClass]:

```
<i
  (click)="setToFav(track.id)"
  [ngClass]="{'fa fa-check': favSongs.includes(track.id), 
  'fa fa-plus': !favSongs.includes(track.id)}"
></i>
```

As said before, it does work but only when you refresh. I'm looking for something like React, when you update the class the component get re-rendered.

Comment: What does `setToFav` do? Because the behaviour you want is how Angular works, so there is something else wrong with your code. There is no need to refresh a page for this to work. Have you changed the changedetection strategy?

Comment: This is what it does http://prntscr.com/nhx9u5

Comment: You never modify the actual `favSongs` array, but instead local storage. Your component doesn't know how to listen to local storage, so that's why it doesn't work. The answer provided to this questions makes a suggestion to reassign the array to a new value where you've pushed the new favorite song, which should work just fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change detection only fires when the *value* of a binding has changed.  The value for primitives is their value, and for objects its the value of their reference.

Adding a track to an array of tracks will mutate the binded object, but not change its reference, and not trigger change detection.

This is one reason for using immutable objects.

In `setToFav` you could do `faveSongs = faveSongs.push(track.id).slice();` or so.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, `favSongs` never gets updated: it gets value assigned in the `ngOnInit` (so, once in the lifetime of the component), and that's it. `setToFav` only manipulates local storage (`favSongs` doesn't automatically get updated, you have to to it explicitly).