# Angular doesn't detect swiper slide changes

Tags: angular, onchange, swiper.js, ngonchanges

I'm using [swiper library](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/). In API from above link you can find that `mySwiper.activeIndex` is returning currectly selected slide. What I want to do is update my service whenever slide is changed so my app will know which slide is selected in other parts (by sharing service).

So what I wanted to use is `ngOnChanges` which suppose to detect every change in component but it doesn't detect slide change because my code doesn't `console.log` anything. Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import {TouchService} from "../../services/touch.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-nav',
    templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './nav.component.scss' ]
})
export class NavComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnInit {
    mySwiper: Swiper;

    slides = [
        'Slide1',
        'Slide2',
        'Slide3',
        'Slide4',
        'Slide5',
        'Slide6'
    ];

    constructor(private touchService: TouchService) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.mySwiper = new Swiper('.nav', {
            paginationClickable: false,
            grabCursor: true,
            loop: true,
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 50
        });

        this.mySwiper.on('touchStart', () => {
            this.touchService.triggerTouchStart();
        });
        this.mySwiper.on('touchEnd', () => {
            this.touchService.triggerTouchStop();
        });
    }
    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log(changes);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert(this.mySwiper.activeIndex);
        }, 4000);
    }
}
```

In this code setTimeout works correctly and show me currently selected slide after 4 seconds from app load. But this `ngOnChanges(changes) {` seems to be never fired because I don't see any console.logs.

Why ngOnChanges doesn't catch `mySwiper` changes? What can I do to detect such changes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons this doesn't work:

Firstly, `ngOnChanges()` will only fire when one of the component's bound properties has changed, e.g. an `@Input` variable.

[ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges):

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change
>   detector has checked data-bound properties if at least one has changed

Secondly, even if Swiper was an input property, mutations to the Swiper object would not cause change detection to fire, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891303/angular-ngclass-ngif-not-rerendering-on-changes/55891568#55891568); only a reference change to a data-bound object property will.

**Solution**

Run your 'changes' code when the touchEnd event occurs:

`this.mySwiper.on('touchEnd', () => {
            this.touchService.triggerTouchStop();
            // Your code here.
        });`